# Generate ranges from list of values

Tags: java

I have a numbers List as below

## 1,2,4,5,6,10

And I want the result as below

## 1-2, 4-6, 10-10

Any Idea (in java)?

Comment: Yes, I am fairly sure I could implement it. But this isn't a code writing service - it's a help forum. So what can we _help_ you with?

Comment: You provide an example but don't explain what you want in the general case. This is unusal, generally we get people describing the general case with no example. However, both make bad questions

Comment: Hint: start by writing a code fragment to identify a sequence of consecutive numbers.

Comment: First try writing some code, come back and post if you need any help with what you have.

Comment: Found the way. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n[]={1,2,4,5,6,10};
int len=n.length-1;
String startRange = "";
String endRange = "";

for (int k = 0; k<=len;k++)
        {
            startRange = String.valueOf(n[k]);

            for (int l = k; l<len;l++)
            {
                if (n[l+1]-n[l]!=1)
                {
                    endRange = String.valueOf(n[l]);
                    k=l;
                    break;
                }
                if (l==len-1)
                {
                    endRange = String.valueOf(n[l+1]);
                    k=l+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k==len)
            {
                endRange = String.valueOf(n[k]);
            }
            System.out.println("Range :: " + startRange + "," + endRange);              
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the list

```
int[] array = {1,2,4,5,6,10};
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  // write your code
}
```